# Getting redirected to http://stackexchange.com/promos

Tags: support, bug, redirection

All of a sudden I am getting redirected to https://stackexchange.com/promos when I am trying to access https://stackoverflow.com/.

The other Stack Exchange websites are working perfectly and I already tried it on a different computer as well. What is going wrong?

Comment: They probably are using the onld winterba.sh api urls somewhere in the script, and thr 302 redirect breaks things.

Comment: Then again, iirc the whole code was written so as to take the url as a parameter to `WinterBash.init()` and nowhere else. So that should not happen.

Comment: Do you know how to use the developer tools in your browser? The network tab should tell you what redirects are taking place. I certainly don't see the behaviour you are talking about however.

Comment: As Martijn said, we need to see what's redirecting you there - it's very likely an old winterbash script you have installed (or insanely cached..don't know how that'd happen unless a *really* bad proxy is in play).  Take a look and see what's sending you there, we certainly aren't currently, but knowing what the original request that causes the 301/302 is will help us advise you further in tracking it down.

Comment: @NickCraver How should I see what's sending me there?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.