# Stack Overflow is redirecting to stackpromos

Tags: support, redirection

When I am trying to open [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) through Google Chrome it is redirecting me to [stackpromos](http://stackpromos.com/promos). I couldn't find any path to access Stack Overflow. It is accessible through the Firefox at the same time.

What is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212586/312043

Comment: Also reported here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340371/73226

Comment: I don't think that closing as a duplicate of a 2013 question is useful.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339905/4386651. Both are from 2016, the one I linked is roughly a week older, and not closed.